# mysql timestamp conversion/formatting Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered

Tags: php, mysql, date, formatting, timestamp

In my database I have set row "posted" as a timestamp but I get this notice when trying to convert/format it:

```
Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered
```

code:

```
$posted = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', $row['posted']);
    echo $posted;
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `var_dump($row['posted']);` show?  Maybe you need to call `strtotime()` on `$row['posted']` first?

Comment: It just calls the timestamp row, this is first time playing with timestamp option usually I just set it to varchar and update it with the date, I'm guessing I need to add more then?

Comment: The second parameter to `date()` needs to be a unix timestamp, so if the data in the `posted` column is not a timestamp, you have to convert it to one first.  I'm guessing it is in `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` format which means you have to use `strtotime` first.

Comment: Thanks drew010, sorry I don't seem to have the +1 option to mark your answer, not sure if its a privilege thing or not.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This means that the second parameter for `date()` is expecting integer, so convert `$row['posted']` to timestamp first.

Try

```
$posted = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($row['posted']));
```